# How to make top navbar alignment for left right center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to make top navbar left side logo and center text and right text as size of logo. i able to make left left side logo on top navbar and text on right side of the top navbar but unable to make some text in the center other top navbar, even facing the problem to make right side text(i tried to add clearflex) size as logo.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- Theme CSS -->

<link
 href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
 rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Favicon -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
<script
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
 src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>
.bs-example {
 margin: 20px;
 font-weight: 700px;
}


</style>

</head>

<body>


 <!------Top navbar------------->
 <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container fluid">
   <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
     data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"
     aria-expanded="false">
     <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
      class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
      class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo1.jpg"
     height="48" width="202" class="pull-left"></a>
   </div>

   <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"
    id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li class="active"><a href="#"
      style="color: blue; margin-left: 6em">Ticket top displaying
       important things/ messages/ reminders/ tax dates/ Times
       reminders </a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li><div class="navbar-brand">Experiencing </div></li>
     <!--    <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="color: blue;">First Name Last name <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <center> <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li></center>
           
          </ul>
        </li>-->
    </ul>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

   </div>

  </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried to do like this image:

[image: I tried to do like this image]

Comment: Why are you including Bootstrap twice?

Comment: Seems some issue with the bootstrap's version of css you are using.If you have to use bootstrap version 3, then prefer using 3.3.7 version. It was a stable one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these styles

```
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
   padding: 0;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Theme CSS -->

<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Favicon -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico">

<script
 src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
 src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>
.bs-example {
 margin: 20px;
 font-weight: 700px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
   padding: 0;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
 }

</style>

</head>

<body>


 <!------Top navbar------------->
 <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container fluid">
   <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
     data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"
     aria-expanded="false">
     <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
      class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
      class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo1.jpg"
     height="48" width="202" class="pull-left"></a>
   </div>

   <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"
    id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li class="active"><a href="#"
      style="color: blue; margin-left: 6em">Ticket top displaying
       important things/ messages/ reminders/ tax dates/ Times
       reminders </a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li><div class="navbar-brand">Experiencing </div></li>
     <!--    <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="color: blue;">First Name Last name <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <center> <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li></center>
           
          </ul>
        </li>-->
    </ul>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

   </div>

  </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```